# Distance to origin of 2 connected lines that have a pivot where they conect

Tags: geometry

Line A starts at the origin, is $1$ unit long and ends at $(1,0)$
Line B is connected to Line A at A's end $(1,0)$ and is $1$ unit long ending at $(2,0)$
So far the line AB is $2$ units from the origin.

Imagine that the meeting point of AB $(1,0)$ is a pivot where the line A remains on the X axis and line B can increase or decrease in angle from the X axis.  If at the pivot point, line B increases in angle $90$ degrees the end point of line B would be at the point $(1,1)$ and the distance from the end of line B to the origin would be $\sqrt{1^2+1^2}=\sqrt2$.

My question, if line B pivots up $1$ degree, how do I determine the new length of the end point of B to the origin.

For clarity, if line B were to pivot $180$ degrees the end of line B would low be at the origin.

Not sure of a way to better explain the problem

Thanks in advance for any help

John

Comment: sorry my formula did not post correctly, its just pythagorean's theorem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$d=\sqrt{(1+cos\theta)^2+sin^2\theta}=\sqrt{(1+cos1^\circ)^2+sin^21^\circ}\approx1.999924$$

Comment: Perhaps not necessary as OP asked in degrees, but maybe add that in the formula, $\theta$ is in degrees. [And +1]

Comment: @coffeemath Good point. I added it. And thanks!

Comment: Thank you very much KK.  Can I ask a further question, I tried searching on google for a solution prior to asking.  I think the issue I was having is actually knowing what the question was. . .could you please reference a web explanation so I can learn the logic behind your answer (teach a man to fish kind of thing :-)

Comment: Hi John, the question is what the distance between the origin and the end of the line B. The line A is fixed and you anchor one end of the line B to the tip of the line A, and you rotate the line B like you draw a circle that has its center at $(1,0)$ and radius of $1$. The question was asking that when you rotate the line B by 1 degree and what's the distance between the far end of the line B and the origin. I'm not sure if my explanation is helpful. Or if you can point me to the web you found then I'll try to explain based on that.

Comment: LOL, sorry KK, you are correct, that is the question. . .what I meant was that I did not know how to put it in a small "google worthy" question in order to find a suggested solution.  Something like "length of cord given arc angle" or something succinct like that.

Answer (score 0):

We can also do by taking the cosine component of $AB$. so length $d=1+1\cos1^\circ=1+0.99842\ldots\approx1.99842$ . Hope it's clear